# bootstrap popover advanced position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have text on the page with several inputs in it. When the button is clicked popovers near every input show up and they can be placed over each other and other inputs. This should not happen, and i don't know how to prevent it. Maybe there is a script that checks if the element is over another element, and if it is, then place popover in different direction?

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CIXKk.png)

The code for each popover:

```
 function show(){
      $('#gap1').popover({
          placement: 'auto right',
          html: 'true',
          content : 'popover text',
      }).popover('show');
 }
```

All the popovers are shown when the button is clicked:

```
 <button type='button' onclick='show()'>Show</button>
```

As shown on the screenshot, when all the popovers are shown, they can be put on top of each other or on top of nearby inputs. That is what I want to prevent. For exmple, when when button is clicked, the second popover must be shown on the left from its input, because on the right there is another input with its own popover.

Comment: Which javascript's event you use in your code? `onmousehover`?

Comment: please post your code or make a fiddle at http://www.jsfiddle.net

Comment: what are you trying to prevent? the popovers full stop? or do you just want to amend the positioning and keep the popups? Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve